# InvalidDocument: key must not contain '.' and insert_one()

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x, lighthouse

Hey I have a json from https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse which i want to store with pymongo to a mongodb. There are some keys with dots, thus i get these errors:

InvalidDocument: key '74245.20' must not contain '.'

with just insert there was a check_keys=False option. Is there anything similar with insert_one?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't support keys with a dot in them, you should replace the dot. 
In the Mongo Doc, it is suggested to use the Unicode  (U+FF0E (i.e. “．”)).

Comment: Could you provide a reference here?